# dbUnit - how to define where no primary key exists, to use all columns of table

Tags: java, hibernate, dbunit

I'm having difficult with dbUnit's `org.dbunit.dataset.NoPrimaryKeyException`. I've got a class, let's say `A`, that has a `Set<B>` property, where `B` is an `enum`. I use Hibernate's `hbm2ddl` tool to generate my database schema, and then use `dbUnit` to populate my database ready for DAO unit testing.

I'm trying to populate my database using dbUnit xml, but I'm getting a `org.dbunit.dataset.NoPrimaryKeyException` when dbUnit tries to delete the entries I've defined for the table `A_B` (that has been auto generated by Hibernate)

I've had a look at the solution proposed on the following question:
[Using DbUnit with tables which do not have primary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131033/using-dbunit-with-tables-which-do-not-have-primary-keys), but this requires that I either:

- Define an `id` for each and every class as a primary key (I already have primary keys defined that are not necessarily numeric); or
- Specify exactly which primary keys are used for which classes in the `accept` method.

*Is there any way that I can specify the default primary key should be used, **unless there isn't one**, in which case we should use all columns in the table?*

(As an aside, I persist the enum using Hibernate and JPA annotations using a similar method to that described at http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Java+5+Enums+Persistence+with+Hibernate)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318037/noprimarykeyexception-from-dbunit-when-loading-a-dataset-into-a-database?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the direction, but as I'm using enums (with the table effectively being generated on the fly - no corresponding table for the actual enum itself), I'm not quite sure how I would implement the solution?

Comment: Could you paste your code? It will be easier to help you. Are you using @Enumerated?